# How to get GIFs "out of sync"

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, animated-gif

I'm trying to reliably load the same GIF, but have it play at different times.

Overall, I expected to find a spec that would tell me what the rules were for rendering (i.e. what's in sync what's out of sync), but I haven't been able to find any such standard. Is there any spec for how GIFs are rendered with respect to timing?

Consider these examples:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwWBD.gif [image: banana][image: banana]
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwWBD.gif?blah=1 [image: banana][image: banana]
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/3As1l.gif [image: banana][image: banana]

Safari, seems to keep everything in sync regardless of the URL. Chrome on the initial load has the timings separate by URL, but eventually has them in sync. Firefox seems to depend solely on the URL without any parameters to determine syncing.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a programming question here or is this just curiosity?

Comment: I would think if you used developer tools in any browser and threw a querystring on the end of any of those URLs then the one you changed would be moving separately from the others.

Answer (score 4):

Tested on Chrome, abney317's answer works for me. I was able to get staggered start times by adding a query string to the end of the URL.

```
const image = document.querySelector('img');
img.src = imgUrl + '?id=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
```